# MySQL - Transferring data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a date column (Date, INDEX) in my MySQL database but because I have some advanced date queries to make, I have to transfer the day and month in to a new column, 'shortDate'.

The advanced queries include seasonal searches, so I can search for all photos from summer/winter/autumn/spring/christmas/new year/easter but from *any* year. This allows me to run queries like this, for summer:

```
...WHERE shortDate BETWEEN 0621 AND 0921...;"
```

So the new column (shortDate) should look like this:

```
Date                shortDate
2011-01-28          0128
2011-06-17          0617
2011-12-22          1222
```

I have created the new column but I would like to know the fastest solution to transfer/convert the date column and write the conversion to the new column? Is this all possible in SQL or do I need to include another server language?

I have 150,000 rows and could take a while if I don't do it the *right* way. Because my SQL skills are very rusty, I probably would have written some ASP to read, covert and insert the new data but I'm hoping there is a quicker way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
Update YourTable
set shortDate = date_format(`Date`, '%m%d')
```

This will take care of your **existing data**. You have to make sure any new data entered in the table will follow the same rule.

You can either do that in the application that inserts the data or by creating a trigger in the table responsible for handling the content of `shortdate`.

Comment: Mmmm looks simple, thanks Adrian. I will apply this now and see how it goes. I will add a trigger also.